# rails hash of date functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, hash

I have some reocure's model, that has frequencies and should create several records on it's own creation.
I'm trying to convert the integer frequency (1,7,30) to a function of (days, weeks, months) Respectively, so I can add this to the new records.

I tried doing it by using a hash of date functions, in order to use it like `date+i.months()`:

```
date_hash={1=>days(), 7=>weeks(), 30=>months()}
```

but I'm getting an error.

It should be used inside of a loop:

```
some_number.times do |i|   
    Record.create({...., :date => start_date+i.(date_hash[frequency]),....}) 
end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `days' for # <MyController:0x111111>
```

Thanks for your assist.

Comment: I am not sure, your code looks cryptic. Can you please post your actual code or probably be more clear of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to do? Do you want to add 1 day, 7 weeks and 30 months to a given date?

Comment: no, this only represent the frequency - if it's 1 - need to add (1 day * current iteration), 7 - (add week * current iteration), 30 - (add month *cuurent iteration)

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of not-Ruby here. Ruby doesn't provide first-class functions like you seem to expect (`date()` would assign the value of that key to the result of the invocation of some function named `date` available in the local scope), and you can't call a variable method name like that. In Ruby, method calls on objects (receivers) are messages sent to the receiver, with optional arguments. The typical way you would call something like this is by using `Object#send` with the desired method name:

```
methods = {1 => :days, 7 => :weeks, 30 => :months}
x.send(methods[1])  # Calls x#days
```

However, the intent of your code is rather unclear, and there is likely a much better-factored way of doing what you want.

Comment: I have added more information anyway, about the real logic - so you can check if there's some better way doing it (although it looks pretty good for me :).